# Return something based on the number of time it appears in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

```
id cars     price
1  bmw
1  corvette
1  mercedes
2  bmw
3  bmw
3  toyota
4  bmw
4  honda
5  lotus
```

I found this table from another post and just wanted to use it for my question.

Suppose the ids represent owners and they own multiple cars and some owners have the same car.

I want to write a query such that given a number n and an owner(id)

I can return the cars that the owner has and there are a total of n of these cars in the table.

For example if 
I'm given id 1 and n = 4 then it will return 
bmw
if I'm given id 1 and n = 1 then it will return 
corvette
mercedes

I figured out that

```
select cars from table group by cars having count(cars) = 4
```

Gives me all the cars that appear 4 times in the table but I want to narrow it down to a car that is owned by a certain car owner.

Thanks for helping

Comment: build a derived table where returns the distinct count of the cars as a subquery column and grouped cars and id.. the main query will filter your distinct count and/or id and should return the relative car

Comment: How do I  do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 3 :

```
select * from 
(
    select f1.*, rownumber() over(partition by f1.car) rang 
    from yourtable f1
) f2
where f2.rang=4 and f1.id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 :

```
with totalcar
(
select car, count(*) nb
from yourtable
group by car
)
select * from yourtable f1 inner join totalcar f2 on f1.car=f2.car
where f1.id=1 and f2.nb=4
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 :

```
select * from yourtable f1 
inner join lateral
(
  select f2.car
  from yourtable f2
  where f1.car=f2.car
  group by f2.car
  having count(*)=4
) f3 on 1=1
where f1.id=1
```